# http to https redirect url using web.config but getting HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was try to redirect http to https url using web.config and change in web.config as below code. but it was getting error of "**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**"
But if i remove this code in web.config its working fine. so can you help me what should do change in it or something wrong in it.

```
<rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think If you want make requests to HTTPS.
You should follow this steps,

- SSL Certificate for site should be installed.
- Site properly installed and configured for SSL (site set up and binding in IIS configured).
- URL Rewrite is installed on the server.

one more thing the code which you written url rewrite it is correct.

Comment: URL Rewrite is installed on the server.. That is right

Comment: download from here: [Microsoft Url ReWrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)